# Passing strrev() as an argument to a function to print reverse string is not working

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, reverse

The task is to pass reverse string of a given string and print it in the function.

When I was trying to do that the code is printing the actual string instead of reverse string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void function(char*);
int main() 
{
        char x[]="Hello";
        printf("\nPassing: %s\n",x);
        function(x);
        printf("\nPassing: %s\n",strrev(x));
        function(strrev(x));

}
void function(char mainstr[])
{
    printf(" >Recieved mainstr=%s",mainstr);
}
```

Output of the above code is:

```
Passing: Hello
 >Recieved mainstr=Hello
Passing: olleH
 >Recieved mainstr=Hello
```

What is the mistake in this code. Can anyone please elaborate?, Thank you.

Comment: `strrev()` reverses the string in place. So it's normal you receive in the second function the reverse string of `"olleH"` which is `"Hello"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `strrev` twice. The second call undoes the effects of the first call. If you want to keep the string reversed, don't call `strrev` again as reversing the same string twice puts it back the way it was.